# Connecting 2 ventilators to the same output?

Tags: output

So i have an output of 5V 1A, and i want to connect 2, 5V 0.15A ventilators to the same output, and the question is - will there be enough voltage for both of them(because i have 1A output, and both of them would only need 0.30A)? Or do i still need 10 V?

Answer (score 1):

Wire them in parallel, not series, so that they each see 5V.  The total current will still be within the limit of 1A.